# Why the player Id is empty from oneSignal on Xamarin? Just in iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, onesignal

I'm having a little problem getting the player Id from Xamarin. I'm making an application in Xamarin Forms, it works for Android, but when I try to get it on iOS the string is Empty.

Then, when I want to get the value of "playerId" (My var) it is Empty. This happens just in iOS--when I do this on Android it works fine.
Obviously before I register the app with the OneSignal Key, my device(iPhone) is registered on the OneSignal page. I need get the playerId to save it on my DataBase.

This is my code:

```
string playerId="";

    OneSignal.Current.IdsAvailable(new Com.OneSignal.Abstractions.IdsAvailableCallback((playerID, pushToken) =>
                                {
                                    playerId = playerID;
                                }));
```

Comment: The method you use seems deprecated and you  can try the latest [idsavailable](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk#section--idsavailable-) method to get the userID. Also make sure you have [set up successfully](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup#section-setup-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already moved on from this issue, but I was facing the same thing.

After some digging, what I found was apparently there can be quite a delay between the time your app starts and the time the IdsAvailable Callback gets executed by the OneSignal SDK (it is after all a callback so there's no gurantee you will still be in that routine by the time it gets run)

On my devices, for android it's almost instant, for iOS it takes roughly 2 seconds from the time my app starts to the time the Id is available, so I simply had to make accommodations for the fact that the Player Id might not be available when my first view loads.